# Display an element upon Selecting a Drop-Down Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have a question. I am trying to create a theme for Genesis Framework. I am having trouble with one Element.

I have two drop down lists. But I only Want the Second one to appear when A specific item is selected from the First Drop-down List. Consider this is the first drop down list.

`<select name="jquery_box" id="jquery_box">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="fancybox">Fancybox</option>
    <option value="colorbox">Colorbox</option>
</select>`

Now I want A Second Drop-down list to appear but only when I have selected the the Third option in the first drown down menu. "Colorbox"

I am doing something with PHP and It is working too but it does not work in real-time. It only works when I select the third option save the settings and the page refreshes. I need some JavaScript solution for it to Appear on selecting third option with value="colorbox" and disappear if another Option is selected.

Please I will be very grateful if you help me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$('#jquery_box').change(function() {
    if(this.value == "colorbox") {
        $('#second_select').show();
    } else {
        $('#second_select').hide();
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvf9v/1/)**

or shorten above code using `.toggle()`:

```
$('#jquery_box').change(function () {
    $('#second_select').toggle(this.value == "colorbox");
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvf9v/2/)**

Comment: All right It is working in your Fiddle Demo just the Way I was asking thank you. I am not being able to do that on my code though maybe because there is a lot of Php.

Comment: Hello Sir it is working. Thank you very very much. The second example works. There is one problem "#second_select" only appears when "colorbox" value is clicked. If Value "colorbox" is saved like if is the default option on page load "#second_select" does not appear. I have to select another option and then "colorbox" again then '#second_select' appears. Thank you again